# how to populate map-reduced result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
TestSessionSchema.statics.getTopTesters = function(callback){
    var o = {};
    o.map = function(){
        emit(this._customer, this.points);
    };

    o.reduce = function(_customer, values){
        var result = {_customer: _customer, sum_points: 0, };
        values.forEach(function(point){
            result.sum_points += point;
        });
        return result;
    };

    o.out = { replace: 'createdCollectionNameForResults' };
    o.verbose = true;

    this.mapReduce(o,function(err, model, stats){
        model.find().sort({'value.sum_points': "desc"}).limit(5).populate("_customer").exec(function(error, results){

            log(results);

        })
    });

}
```

In map-reduce part I am geting _customers' points.

Now i want to populate _customer to get customers' info
 `model.find().sort({'value.sum_points': "desc"}).limit(5).populate("_customer")` does not work

how can I do it?

Comment: you are not using the correct format in "result" (or in emit).  The second part of emit must be identical format to what reduce returns as "result".  So either emit(this._customer, {_customer:this._customer, sum_points:this.points}  OR  make result format simple "result = 0" to represent points.

Comment: btw, it would be helpful if you separated the potential issue.  Do a simple select from your createdCollectionNameForResults collection to make sure you're outputting what you think you are.  When that looks okay, then try the second part - and post the error you get when it "does not work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do mapReduce in MongoDB, you must make sure that your emit value has the same format as your reduce return value.

That means in your case that if `map` calls `emit(customer, points)` then `reduce` must return simply the value for `points`.

To change your specific example, your map function is okay, but your reduce function should be:

```
reduce = function(_customer, values) {
        var result =  0;
        values.forEach(function(point){
            result += point;
        });
        return result;
    };
```

Your reduce function would then sum up all of the values (points) for each _customer, which is what you want.  The output would be _customer, point as key-value pairs with field names `_id` and `value` where value would be the sum of all the point values for that _id (_customer).

To query the result you would run:

`db.createdCollectionNameForResults.find().sort({value:-1}).limit(5)`